# How to iterate over window of next N elements for each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops

I have a problem with labeling rows in my dataframe. The idea is that I want to know whether current (iterated) value multiplied by small float is higher than any of next 60 rows in the dataframe.

I've already found a solution that works but unfortunately is very slow. I tried to make it with .apply and list comprehension but failed.

The code looks like this:

```
    for i in range(df.shape[0] - 1):
        label.append((df.iloc[i+1:window+i]['value'] > df.iloc[i]['value'] * small_threshold).any())
```

So basically let's say that I have this df

| idx | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.00 |
| 1 | 2.01 |
| 2 | 1.98 |
| 3 | 2.01 |
| 4 | 2.02 |

I would like to label each row with respect to next 3 rows. To make it easier I will skip the multiplication of the current row value. So the goal is to label row as True if any value is higher than current value and False if there is no value (with respect to next 3 rows)

| idx | value | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.00 | true |
| 1 | 2.01 | true |
| 2 | 1.98 | false |
| 3 | 2.01 | NaN |
| 4 | 2.02 | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case check `rolling`

```
df['new'] = df.value.shift(-1).iloc[::-1].rolling(3).max().ge(df.value)
Out[56]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed and works in 1 second instead of couple minutes! You're amazing, thank you very much for your help.